# PostreSql 9.6 2 tasks

Tags: sql

Schema:

```
create table candidates ( 
id int primary key, position 
varchar not null, 
salary int not null 
); 
insert into candidates values (1, 'junior', 10500); 
insert into candidates values (2, 'senior', 15000); 
insert into candidates values (3, 'senior', 35000); 
insert into candidates values (4, 'junior', 8000); insert 
into candidates values (5, 'senior', 30000); insert into 
candidates values (6, 'senior', 25000); insert into 
candidates values (7, 'junior', 30000); insert into 
candidates values (8, 'senior', 50000); insert into 
candidates values (9, 'senior', 30000); insert into 
candidates values (10, 'junior', 7000); insert into 
candidates values (11, 'junior', 8000); insert into 
candidates values (12, 'senior', 33000); insert into 
candidates values (13, 'junior', 5000); insert into 
candidates values (14, 'senior', 47000); insert into 
candidates values (15, 'junior', 12000);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVUQ1.png)

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select   *
        ,sum(salary) over(partition by position order by salary) as "cumulative salary"
from     candidates
order by position desc, salary
```

| id | position | salary | cumulative salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | senior | 15000 | 15000 |
| 6 | senior | 25000 | 40000 |
| 5 | senior | 30000 | 100000 |
| 9 | senior | 30000 | 100000 |
| 12 | senior | 33000 | 133000 |
| 3 | senior | 35000 | 168000 |
| 14 | senior | 47000 | 215000 |
| 8 | senior | 50000 | 265000 |
| 13 | junior | 5000 | 5000 |
| 10 | junior | 7000 | 12000 |
| 11 | junior | 8000 | 28000 |
| 4 | junior | 8000 | 28000 |
| 1 | junior | 10500 | 38500 |
| 15 | junior | 12000 | 50500 |
| 7 | junior | 30000 | 80500 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AFF6Z0tZ?hide=4)

Comment: bro how i reverse position like this one but reversed one senior first then junior

Comment: @ikramirzayev see updated answer